# undefined method `collect' for #<Page:0x007f4f200a9350

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

can anyone help me with this error ? I'm pretty rookie and still not how it works so if anyone can explain to me how to fix this is really appreciate it , now I attached the code which gives me the error

```
3: <%= render :partial => "shared/ubiquo/feedback" %>
4: 
5: <%= show_filter_info %>
6: <%= pages_list(@pages, @pages_pages) %>
7: 
8: <% content_for :sidebar do %>
9: <%= show_filters %>
```

Comment: what is the value of @pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you have something like this written somewhere:

```
@pages = Page.collect #...
```

whereas it ought (in order to use *Enumerable* methods) be:

```
Page.all.collect
```

because Enumerable's [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) operates on array data structure, and `Page.all` is what actually returns this collection.